# Создать volume group для смонтированного root тома

Tags: linux, debian, администрирование

У меня Debian Jessie 8.2 с уже созданным root томом. Пока нет никаких групп для томов. Возможно ли создать группу для смонтированного рут тома? 
Если данные сотрутся - это ок.

Comment: Добрый день! Уточнение - на диске есть root(/) без LVM но вы хотите чтобы был раздел с LVM? если да, то следующий вопрос есть ли свободное пространство под новый том на LVM или весь диск отведен под файловую систему смонтированную в / (root)? df -h (покажет что и куда смонтировано) lsblk (покажет структуру ваших блочных устройств) Если можете киньте вывод этих команд.